# How to remove the Desktop 1 / New Desktop icon from Windows 11 taskbar?

Tags: taskbar, windows-11

There is this annoying and useless icon pinned to the `Windows 11` taskbar that I cannot figure out how to remove:

[image]

When I hover over it, it shows "Desktop 1" and "New desktop". I want this icon gone. Right-click does nothing. How is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is this annoying and useless icon pinned to the Windows 11
> taskbar that I cannot figure out how to remove

This is done a different way in Windows 11 but still easy.

Right click on the Task Bar and select Task Bar Settings.

You can turn Task View (Desktop 1) and Widgets and other things OFF as you wish.

Review all the items (4) and enable / disable what you wish.

[image: Windows 11 Task Bar Settings]

Comment: Thank you John. Turning off Task view seems to have automatically removed that icon BUT I do not see a list of items I can turn on/off separately. I have seen screenshots of of this in other places, but I can't find it.

Comment: The list of 4 things in the screen shot is the complete list for the Microsoft built in icons.